# How to show images in xamarin forms using gridview?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin forms please suggest me how to shows images with some text in xamarin forms . Like i want to show 3 images horizontally in a row and want to add more rows vertically and want to show some information about image in xamarin cross platform application. Every Image will have information about image at below of image. I am using PCL and please try to help in xamal do not want to write in c# code? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
var grid = new Grid();
grid.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new    GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star)});
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) });

        var alpha = new Image { Source = "pic1.png" };
        var beta = new Image { Source = "pic2.png" };
        var gamma = new Image { Source = "pic3.png" };
        var delta = new Image { Source = "pic4.png" };
        var epsilon = new Image { Source = "pic5.png" };
        var theta = new Image { Source = "pic6.png" };

        grid.Children.Add(alpha, 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(beta, 1, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(gamma, 2, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(delta, 0, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(epsilon, 1, 1);
        grid.Children.Add(theta, 2, 1);

        Content = new ScrollView
        {

            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Content = grid,


        };
```

Comment: hello I have tried its fine but is there any way to put images in stack Layout horizontally and when image overlap with device screen size then it comes to new line means new row an so on ?